# python TypeError: frozenset expected at most 1 arguments, got 4

Tags: python, types, frozenset

I'm getting this error when trying to make a frozen set:

```
class Transcriber:

    DNA_BASES = frozenset('A','T','G','C')
...
```

And this is the Traceback:

```
~/python/project5$ python wp_proj5.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wp_proj5.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Transcriber:
  File "wp_proj5.py", line 7, in Transcriber
    DNA_BASES = frozenset('A','T','G','C')
TypeError: frozenset expected at most 1 arguments, got 4
```

What is wrong here? Can't I initialize a frozenset with more than one string?

Comment: Works better, and easier to type too: `frozenset('ATGC')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an iterable like a list:

```
frozenset(['A','T','G','C'])
```

You can read about it here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset